# How to get input component's value by index in ajax listener method?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm dynamically generating a `#{materielBean2.nbrsalle}` amount of dropdowns:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="#{materielBean2.nbrsalle}" var="i">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="p#{i}" value="#{materielBean2.pole}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Pole" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{materielBean2.poles}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="s#{i}" listener="#{materielBean2.salleChange(i)}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</c:forEach>
```

I have a `Map<String, String>` property where I'd like to save the selected values.

```
private Map<String, String> selectedPoles = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The ajax change listener method is as follows:

```
public void sallechange(int i) {
    selectedPoles.put(i, pole);
}
```

How do I get the selected `pole` value of index `i` in the listener method?

Comment: Did you try: sallechange(int i, poleType pole); listener="#{materielBean2.salleChange(i,materielBean2.pole)}" ?

Comment: the problem is how to get the value of each pole not how to set it

Comment: You want to get the selected pole value of index i in the listener method, so second parameter get this, that is my suggestion.

Comment: no the list of poles is full , it contains every selected pole with its index , but for example when I refresh the page, I must have the same value previously selected  for each selectonemenu ,but in the get of pole i dont know the index of each one.

Comment: value="#{materielBean2.pole}", materielBean2.pole is an instance of Pole type ?

Comment: i'm sorry , there was an error in the question , i corrected it.

Comment: pole is the id of Pole type , poles is a map of <poleId , poleName> . and selectedpoles is map of selected pole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the input value to that map directly.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="p#{i}" value="#{materielBean2.selectedPoles[i]}">
```

You only need to change the map to take integer keys.

```
private Map<Integer, String> selectedPoles = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Or perhaps just use a simple array which can be accessed exactly the same way.

```
private String[] selectedPoles = new String[poles.size()];
```

Either way, this way you can get rid of the `<p:ajax>` altogether. JSF will magically set it for you.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="p#{i}" value="#{materielBean2.selectedPoles[i]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Pole" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{materielBean2.poles}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: it wooooooorks as you say "magically", thanks a lot , i really like it,